# CAML Query when using Or fails giving "Cannot complete this action"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, caml-query, caml

I am creating an SPFX web part which queries a list in SharePoint Online

This works fine:

```
camlQuery = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query>"
```

It brings back all values from the list.

However if I try to just bring back certain rows:

```
camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where>";

        camlQuery += "<Or>";
        camlQuery += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsj</Value></Eq>";
        camlQuery += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsa</Value></Eq>";
        camlQuery += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsb</Value></Eq>";

        camlQuery += "</Or>";
        
        camlQuery += "</Where></Query></View>";
```

I get the error:

> Error making HttpClient request in queryable [500] Internal Server Error ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147467259, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot complete this action.\n\nPlease try again."}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CAML query in this format:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsj</Value></Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsa</Value></Eq>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>bloggsb</Value></Eq>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Note**

> The **Or** element can be nested inside other **Or** and And elements. The server supports unlimited complicated queries. However, any given **Or** element can have **only two child elements**. If you need to join three or more conditions, you must nest the **Or** elements.

**Documentation**: [Or element (Query)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/or-element-query)

**Update from comments**:

You can write CAML query in below format for 6 users:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user1</Value></Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user2</Value></Eq>
                    <Or>    
                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user3</Value></Eq>
                        <Or>    
                            <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user4</Value></Eq>
                            <Or>    
                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user5</Value></Eq>
                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='onPremisesSamAccountName'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>user6</Value></Eq>
                            </Or>
                        </Or>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Comment: That worked many thanks Ganesh. If I have 10 users to check does it follow the same format? My problem is that the amount of users changes. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, you have to follow same format - Use only 2 child statements inside OR element with nesting.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a better way to build a caml query to only show the rows where onPremisesSamAccountName = "user1;user2;user3;user4;user5;user6;" ?

Comment: Check updated answer for example of more complex query.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh I have a follow up question here :) https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306502/how-to-build-a-caml-query-from-a-string-of-data-in-javascript

Comment: Sure, I have previously created a JavaScript function for dynamically generating such CAML queries. Let me find it and I will share it as an answer on your post.

Comment: You're a star Ganesh!